# What is the default font in macvim, and how does one check this?

Tags: unix, vim, macvim

I know how to **change** the font properties, but I don't know how to check what the **default** one is. I would appreciate if someone showed me how to check what the default font is.

Answer (score 3):

1. Start MacVim without any vimrc or plugins with the `mvim` script bundled with MacVim:

   ```
   $ mvim -u NONE -U NONE --noplugin
   ```
2. Ask the question directly to MacVim:

   ```
   :set guifont?
   ```

But I think that you will get an empty string (the default value, see `:h guifont`) and that MacVim is simply using Mac OS X's default monospace font, probably Monaco… or maybe Menlo if you are on Lion.

May I ask you what you intend to do with that information?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I get an empty string like you said. I was just curious as to how to check it, as I was getting quite frustrated as to why I was able to change the font but not know how to check the original default. Also, I quite like the font so may want to use it on other text editors. In the case that it is just the default font for Mac OS X, how do I check that? Have recently migrated from Windows and am tripping up with the most basic of things! Thanks alot for your reply again.

Comment: For years, Monaco was the only programming-friendly font installed by default so it was the de facto default font for every native code editor. I've read somewhere that Mac OS X now ships with another font, Menlo, but I don't know if Monaco is gone or if it's still there. You could use `/Applications/Utilities/FontBook.app` to see for yourself. You could also download MacVim's source and open the `.nib` files in XCode.app or InterfaceBuilder.app (if you have it) and see if it's set there.

Answer (score 2):

You might find the information you want using the menu. Click Edit > Font > Show Fonts. Looks like menlo is my default and monaco is still an option. I'm not sure how to set the default yet. Maybe it's not good form for stack overflow usage, but I think it would be cool if you posted a link to that. They are closely related problems.